# Pandas - combine some values within a column with another column

Tags: python, pandas

New to python and I have been trying to find a solution here (close, but not exactly the same scenario).

Let's say I have 2 columns:
`ID1 = ['ABC12a', 'ABC12b', 'ABC12c']` and `ID2 = ['123','234','345']`

I want to merge these 2 columns into 1, but only retain partial characters of column ID1 (ID1[:3]) and all of column ID2.

So the end result should look like:
`ID1 = ['ABC123','ABC234','ABC345']`

I tried something like:

`df['ID1'] = df['ID1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(x[:3],str(df['ID2'])))`

and this did not work at all...any help is super appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['ID1'] = df['ID1'].str[0:3] + df['ID2']
```

Comment: many thanks! I just had to add 'apply(str)' to the df['ID2'] in addition to your solution

Comment: Great. Note that often you should try to avoid `apply`. It is a good habit to find other ways of solving problems before reaching for `apply`. In this case your columns ID2 was parsed as intergers and could not be added to ID1. The solution is to cast it as string using `.astype(str)`.